# Is there a GWT-compatible Queue implementation?

Tags: gwt

GWT (2.5) emulates [AbstractQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html) but provides no implementations. [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (13.0.1) provides the [Queues](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Queues.html) class but it isn't [GwtCompatible](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/GwtCompatible.html).

Before I proceed to implement my own GWT queue, am I missing an available implementation somewhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) class is emulated by GWT and implements the [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface. GWT emulates all the key queue methods, including `add()` and `remove()`, thus making it perfectly usable as a queue.

Comment: No problem Arun. +1 for `LinkedList` which I totally ignored at first.

Comment: @BorisBrudnoy Glad that was useful